# Spring 3.2 mvc testing a post request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

From the spring tutorial ..

```
MvcResult mvcResult = 
mockMvc.perform(post("/person")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
```

Which is fine and good, but if my controller has the signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postPerson(Person person) {}
```

Where person is a simple DTO normally populated via a spring form in the jsp(with for example two String fields and getter/setters); how to submit that data in the test ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that class `Person` has attributes `name` and `age`.

When building your request, you can do this :

```
post("/person")
  .param("name", "John")
  .param("age", "45")
```